# Why can't this submanifold be a Leaf of a Foliation?

Tags: manifolds, submanifold, foliations

I am studying geometric theory of foliations from Camacho and Lins and I have stumbled upon an afirmation I can't understand.

There is a theorem which states:

> Let F be a leaf of a foliation $\mathcal{F}$ on M  and $\Sigma$ a transverse section
> of $\mathcal{F}$  such that $\Sigma \cap F \neq \varnothing$. We have three possibilities:
>
> 1. $\Sigma \cap F$ is discrete,  and in this case F is an imbedded leaf.
> 2. The closure of  $\Sigma \cap F$ in $\Sigma$ contains an open set.
>    This occurs if and only if the closure $\bar{F}$ has non-empty interior and
>    $int (\bar{F}) = \bar{F} - \partial \bar{F}$ is an open set which contains F. In this case we say
>    F is locally dense.
> 3. The closure of  $\Sigma \cap F$ is a perfect set  (i.e., without isolated points) with empty interior.
>    In this case we say F is an exceptional leaf.)

After this theorem comes the part I don't get. The authours state that the following submanifold $F$ in the picture bellow can't be a leave of any foliation deffined at an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$

[image: picture]

The reason being the point $x$ is an accumulation point of $\Sigma \cap F$ where $\Sigma$ is a transverse segment passing through x, while the same
does not happen with the point y.

I really don't get this. Suppose that upper horizontal part of $F$ containing $y$ was not there. In this case I guess I would have the case (2) of the theorem, right? To me, that upper part simply means I would have another transverse segment $\Sigma'$ passing through $y$, (vertical to the figure), giving me case (1) of the theorem.

Since we are talking about 2 distinct transverse segments, I don't see what is the problem.

I would appreciate any help since I just recently started studying the topic (please be kind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be the space indicated in Figure 2. Note that $F$ is closed, i.e. , $\bar{F}=F$. The boundary $\partial \bar{F}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\partial \bar{F} = \bar{F}\cap (\overline{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus F}) = \bar{F}\cap \mathbb{R}^2=\bar{F}
\end{align*}
Hence we obtain for the interior of $F$ that $\mathrm{int}(\bar{F})=\bar{F}\setminus\bar{F}=\emptyset$ and $2.$ cannot hold.

Let us assume that $\Sigma$ is the vertical line through $x$. Then $F\cap \Sigma$ has isolated points but it is not discrete since $x$ is an accumulation point. Hence neither $1.$ nor $3.$ can hold which implies that $F$ cann't be a leaf of a foliation.

Comment: But I don't get what this has to do with the point y.

Comment: I think that ``while the same does not happen with the point y'' means that the problematic points of $F$ are the accummulation points of the wiggles, i.e. the vertical line where x is. So you should probably interpret this as $F\setminus \{\text{vertical line with x\}$ can be a leaf of a foliation.

Comment: Makes sense,  that's what I thought but I was afraid of missing something